# MongoDB update query (update an array field in document)

Tags: php, mongodb

Here's what the document looks like now.

```
Array
(
    [email] => admin@mysite.com
    [emailQueries] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [21] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [21] => 0
                )

        )

    [last_visit] => 1375050871
)
```

Here's the code I am using to populate the `emailQueries`

```
$arrayValueToAdd = array( (string) $email_id => '0' );

$collection->update( array('email' => $user['email']), 
                     array( '$push' => 
                          array( 'emailQueries' => $arrayValueToAdd ) 
                      )
                  );
```

However, I'd like to simply have the `emailQueries` array look like:

```
[emailQueries] => Array
    (
        [21] => 0
        [22] => 0
    )
```

Probably a simple thing I'm overlooking...

Answer (score 0):

You are using the array operator [push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/#op._S_push) with a data structure that is not considered by MongoDb as an array ([array must have 0-based ascending numeric indexes](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-104)). You must treat it as an object.
So you have 2 choices.

If in `[21] => 0`, the value `0` is useless (and I don't expect so), you can use a true array:

```
"emailQueries" : [21,22]
```

and you can use the `push` operator in the PHP code like this

```
$collection->update( array('email' => $user['email']), 
                     array( '$push' => 
                         array( 'emailQueries' => (string) $email_id ) 
                     ));
```

On the other hand, if you must keep the value `0`, and for instance, increment it, you have to considered your EmailQuery as an object :

```
"emailQueries" : {
    "21" : 0,
    "22" : 0
}
```

So you can use a simple update to add field in `emailQueries` :

```
$collection->update( array('email' => $user['email']), 
                     array( '$set' => 
                         array( 'emailQueries.'.$email_id => 0  ) 
                     ));
```

And the `$inc`, for incrementation :

```
$collection->update( array('email' => $user['email']), 
                     array( '$inc' => 
                         array( 'emailQueries.'.$email_id => 1  ) 
                     ));
```